# authorization_expires_at was not found in order’s transaction Payments app Shopify

Tags: shopify, payment-gateway, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am creating a payment method using Payments app shopify. There are two major confusions that I found during development:

1. I am using kind = “authorization” by setting Payment Capture to Manual from Shopify store admin.
   When I creating a Resolve call of payment session, I place a Date in authorizationExpiresAt that is  1 year from now. Order is successfully created, but in Transactions.json of that order , these is no field of “authorization_expires_at”.

Example:
Response Sent:

```
mutation PaymentSessionResolve(
  $id: ID!,
  $authorizationExpiresAt: DateTime
) {
  paymentSessionResolve(
    id: $id,
    authorizationExpiresAt: $authorizationExpiresAt
  ) {
    paymentSession {
      id
      state {
        ... on PaymentSessionStateResolved {
          code
        }
      }
      nextAction {
        action
        context {
          ... on PaymentSessionActionsRedirect {
            redirectUrl
          }
        }
      }
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

Variables:

```
{
  "id": "gid://shopify/PaymentSession/u0nwmSrNntjIWozmNslK5Tlq",
  "authorizationExpiresAt": "2024-06-16T20:47:55Z"
}
```

So I am confused, will it going to work perfectly or I am doing wrong. When will authorization expire for that order. Is there any fixed limit of authorization expire when manual payment capture is setup. Please help.

2. I want to use Admin Order API, Asset API and Order Webhooks for adding some more features to my payment app. But shopify support person said, it was prohibited to use api’s of admin other than payment app api’s. But currently I implemented and tested and all works fine. So I am worried whether shopify will publish this payments app or reject, if I adds these features. What’s the right way to do. Do I need any other Public app for admin api’s. Please help.

Resolve Payment Session Response with 1 year authorizationExpiresAt:

```
mutation PaymentSessionResolve(
  $id: ID!,
  $authorizationExpiresAt: DateTime
) {
  paymentSessionResolve(
    id: $id,
    authorizationExpiresAt: $authorizationExpiresAt
  ) {
    paymentSession {
      id
      state {
        ... on PaymentSessionStateResolved {
          code
        }
      }
      nextAction {
        action
        context {
          ... on PaymentSessionActionsRedirect {
            redirectUrl
          }
        }
      }
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

Variables:

```
{
  "id": "gid://shopify/PaymentSession/u0nwmSrNntjIWozmNslK5Tlq",
  "authorizationExpiresAt": "2024-06-16T20:47:55Z"
}
```